# Command Scheduler Fail storage s3 laravel 9

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, scheduler

I have a problem with a Laravel scheduler.

In practice, if I write all the code in a controller with a command it works, but if I make the scheduler do it it gives me fail "NUL" 2>&1

I always work with the scheduler and this error has never come up

given that the scheduler works up to a certain point because the zip file is created but then it is not saved in the s3 storage in the controller everything works thank you very much I hope you can help me..

Code commands :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\ZipArchive\ZipArchiveAdapter;

use ZipArchive;

class Backup extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'backup:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Backup foto caricate nell app';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $azienda = User::value('azienda');

        $fileName = time() . $azienda . ".zip";

        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

            $files = File::files(public_path('/images/images'));

            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
                $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
            $zip->close();
        };

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('public' . $fileName, fopen($fileName, 'r'));

        //return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Kernel :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */

     protected $commands = [
        Commands\Backup::class
     ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('backup:name')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to store any file on S3 via the scheduler? create a command that uploads a dummy file to test